# Unwrapping tricky cylinder

Tags: uv

I have a real pain to unwrap a quite complicated model.
The shape is a cylinder that is drilled with multiple holes trough its height. I modeled this part with fusion 360, then imported it as an .obj.

Please have a look at my screen as shown on picture to understand my issue. The unwrapping doesn't work as expected and I can't find a way to make it do what I want...

[image]

Comment: While no one can guess what you "except" or "want", it appears as if you were not using seams. Why? Have you followed any basic unwrapping tutorials?

Comment: What I want is fairly simple...I want the texture to be wrapped nicely without having those strange shapes.
And I know the basics of UV unwrapping so yes, I use seams

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciphering the topology in the holes of the object. It may help, if others can look at your object, you could upload a condensed version of your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The holes aren't that important, as they will be covered by another part.
The most important is the cylinder surface.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation recently. Most online advice was "select one quad and then use the Follow Active Quads thingy", but that wasn't an option for my model.

What helped me was the `Cylinder Projection` unwrap method, with Direction set to "Align to Object" and both the "Correct Aspect" and "Scale to Bounds" checkboxes checked:
[image: "Cylinder Projection" options panel with Direction set to "Align to Object" and both the "Correct Aspect" and "Scale to Bounds" checkboxes checked]

If the holes in your model aren't important and don't actually need to be in your UV map, make sure to deselect them first.

Comment: Will try this as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter W. I found my answer !

I tried the cylinder projection with your requirements but that didn't help
Then, I tried to tweak options with the main unwrapping tool: works quite great with using the "conformal" method option chosen (default is "angle based").

This method only works if I divide the main cylinder into multiple small section..but it works !

[image]